# Starting Websphere 8 in eclipse

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-8

I am using Win7 64 bit and when i try to start websphere 8 inside my eclipse it says

```
Get the following error when  start the server :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:646)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:612)
Could not find the main class: Files.  Program will exit.
```

But when i go to first steps console and run the installation verification, the server starts up and also gets started in eclipse.

Please help.

Comment: Is Files one of your classes?

Comment: You're starting the server from the Servers view?

Comment: Seems that "Files" came from "C:\Program Files"

Comment: @DaveRlz No i dont think Files is my class.

Comment: @dbreaux Yes i was trying to start the server from the Servers view in eclipse.

Comment: @MarcinPłonka : Yes i too think that "Files" came from "C:\Program Files" But not sure how to solv it. Is it because any of the start up scripts has Program Files in it?

Comment: Is it both 64-bit Eclipse (or RAD) and 64-bit WebSphere?

Comment: A good rule is to never install something in folder with spaces in name ;)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this for me was **a recently added environmental variable for `JAVA_HOME`** and corresponding entry of`%JAVA_HOME%\bin` that was added to my Windows `PATH`.  This all seemed to work perfectly well from anything inside a `cmd.exe` prompt/window, but did not work properly for the WAS scripting started in IDEs.  The offending `Program Files` reference was in these variables for me.  Removing these definitions, and restarting the IDE (important!) seemed to fix my issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can't run WAS in basic Eclipse. You have to use Rational Application Developer.

Comment: i don't think starting and stopping a WAS should be a problem with eclipse.

Comment: I am getting the same error with RAD 8 now, The only difference is Instead of FILES this time it says RESOURCE.

Comment: Ticket to IBM Software Support. They'll ask you do to a mustgather log collection to see how the software was installed.   There is something funky because I can get my RAD 8 up in less than 30 minutes.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in IntelliJ all of a sudden - this answer provides zero insight.

Comment: Although this answer is not true, I have up-voted because of sh*tty IBM compatibility issues. Works OK in RAD but headache in Eclipse.